# WordPress option data format

Tags: php, wordpress

What kind of format is this:

```
a:1:{s:12:"_multiwidget";i:1;}
```

... and how can I use it in PHP?

For me it looks like a special JSON format. But with `json_decode` I can get it...

Sorry, for this stupid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It‘s a serialised Object. Try using maybe_unserialize() on it.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/maybe_unserialize/